# Conditional (authorization based) markup in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I'm looking for a way to conditionally display certain markups using authorization, and not just User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.

Since I'm using windows authentication with AD, I'd like to be able to do something like an authorizationattribute directly in the markup, like:

```
@[Authorize {Roles = @"domain\Admin"}]
<div> admin markup</div>
```

I tried using

```
@if(User.IsInRole(@"domain\Admin"))
```

but that didn't work either. Can someone give me a pointer to the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you configured the RoleManager to support your AD roles?  Note that this is separate from the authentication.

In web.config you should have a `roleManager` element inside `system.web` that will allow you to configure for use of AD roles.  Specifically, you will need to enable the manager (`enabled="true"`) and create/specify the provider.

Note that the first approach (`AuthorizeAttribute`) can only be applied to controllers and methods, not within your markup.  The second approach (`User.IsInRole()`) should work for you, though, once everything is configured correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware that the AuthorizeAttribute was for controllers/methods, I was just hoping, someone might know of a cool way of obtaining the same thing in markup. I thought I had already setup the roleprovider correctly in the webconfig, but I'll investigate further - thanks!